# Previous palindrome date

Tags: mathematics, time

2nd of February this year will be a palindrome date, because 02/02/2020 reads the same forwards and backwards. But when was the previous palindrome date?

Comment: What is the first '02' in date? February?

Comment: Leading zeroes and M/D/Y (or D/M/Y, the question isn't clear on which one it is) rarely mix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as the palindrome date's day and month can be obtained by its year,

> Going down one-by-one from 2019, we got the first valid date which is in 2012: 21/02/2012.

Answer (score 5):

For the civilized¹ nations where dates are written MM/DD/YYYY,

> the most recent palindromic day was 11/02/2011.

<sup>*¹for some value of "civilized"*</sup>

Comment: Haha I would call that the opposite of civilized 

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but this is only for the "civilized" part. It really sounds somewhat offending, despite it's only a joke (considering the footnote).
P.S. The truly __civilised__ world does not spell this word "civilized" :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the previous one is

> 9/1/19  (either January 9 or September 1, 2019)

Because

> it meets all the criteria of the question (i.e., the format was not specified and this is a perfectly valid way to write a date)